# Performing 2D cut on 3D cube in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, 2d

I have a 3D cube that's filled with small cubes. After filling it with small cubes, I can see its faces. I want to perform a cut through x, y, or z axis, so that I can see the internal structure at some points. Here is an image of the cube,

[image]

I want to see the internal structure of this cube. After search I found that `slice` can be used. I used this code,

```
figure
  [x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:100);
 v = repmat(magic(100),[1 1 100]);
% 
% % Define the slice plane
 [xi, yi] = meshgrid(1:100);
 zi = xi;
% 
% % Slice it
slice(x,y,z,v,xi,yi,zi);
 drawnow
```

But I get a result with completely different colors. Here is the result,

[image]

Can you please tell me how to fix the code above to produce a cut through an axis? Also, I would really appreciate it if you could explain how this process is done as I don't completely understand the code above.

Comment: What code did you use to create the original cube?  `magic` fills in the array with all different numerical values (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/magic.html).  It looks like you're in an indexed color mode, and the different colors correspond to different values in the magic square.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cxw, I used Hoki's code in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913149/filing-the-entire-volume-of-a-cube-with-small-cubes-in-matlab. Can you please tell me how to make the cut? Also, I read magic documentation you provided, but how can it help us in performing the cut? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Re. the first question - I don't know of a straightforward way to slice your multicube off-hand with Hoki's code (but see below).  [polyxpoly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html) might be helpful, but still requires projection onto the plane of the slice.

Re. the second question - slice is cutting "volumetric data," meaning something like density that has a value at each point in the volume.  The `repmat(magic(...))` line is making a 100x100x100 (3-d) array that has a number at each of the 100*100*100=1,000,000 grid points in the array.  It so happens that those points have different values between 1 and 100^2, so you're getting different colors.

Hoki's code doesn't play well with `slice` because it uses `patch` to make polygons instead of using volumetric data.  An alternative would be to make your cubes volumetrically.  This code should run by itself but - caution - is not tested.  it is independent of Hoki's code you mentioned.

```
face=ones(10,10);        %make a small cube, 10x10x10
middle=zeros(10,10);
middle(1,1:10)=1;
middle(10,1:10)=1;
middle(1:10,1)=1;
middle(1:10,10)=1;
small_cube=cat(3,face,repmat(middle,1,1,8),face);

% Now make an array of them - ten in each direction, so 100x100x100
v=repmat(small_cube,10,10,10);

% Now define the slice plane and slice as above.
[xi, yi] = meshgrid(1:100);
zi = xi;

figure;
slice(x,y,z,v,xi,yi,zi);
drawnow
```

**Edit**: In the above, `0` is for points that are not part of the cube and `1` is for points that are.  This is a [voxel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) representation of a cube.  `face` is for the top and bottom, and `middle` is for a slice of the edges between the top and bottom.  The first `repmat` stacks up eight slices of the middle like a burger patty.  The `cat` puts a `face` on the top and bottom of that stack like the two halves of the bun.  Then the second `repmat` makes the 999 other small cubes in the big cube.

**Edit 2**: Replacing `zeros` with `NaN` in the above code should make the insides of the cube transparent.  (Also not tested!)

Comment: Thanks @cxw, can you please tell me if this is a separated code or it should be added at the end of Hoki's code? Also, what is the role of the 2D matrix middle, and why some points are set to 1? Thank You.

Comment: thanks for asking, actually when I tried the code I got this error, Error using repmat. Too many input arguments. Do you know why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that!  Try `[1,1,8]` and `[10,10,10]` (with square brackets).  Which version of Matlab or octave do you have?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use MATLAB 2012. I will try that.